# Cannot view StoryBoard or Project Targets in Xcode 13.1

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have just upgraded to Xcode 13.1 and both the Target and Storyboard displays XML only.

This is my project Target file view.

```
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
    archiveVersion = 1;
    classes = {
    };
    objectVersion = 52;
    objects = {

/* Begin PBXBuildFile section */
        FE02B2A625CB5E7D00C2B123 /* SectorTime.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = FE02B2A525CB5E7D00C2B123 /* SectorTime.swift */; };
        FE0340BC2169997900803E4C /* TransactionNumberGenerator.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = FE0340BB2169997900803E4C /* TransactionNumberGenerator.swift */; };
        FE036EF7245D116000C9D3A1 /* ArchiveImport.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile;
```

The "Open As" options are missing from the menu when I right click on the storyboard file in the project navigator:

[image: Open As options missing when right click on storyboard]

Anyone have any ideas? I have done a clean build and I restarted both Xcode and my Mac.

Comment: Are you perhaps not viewing it in the standard editor: eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/33552200/1032372 ?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, I did find the problem. The editor remained in "Code Review" mode after the automatic upgrade to Xcode 13.1. By pressing "Disable Code Review" in the top right-hand corner, I fixed everything.

It was not an obvious fix because the Code Review mode remained on across different files I selected. Also, because my source code was up to date, there were no differences in my Swift code files, so they all looked original, whereas Storyboard and Targets seemed quite different.

Comment: This was a bad problem. It ate my launch! I uploaded my project built with an earlier XCode into XCode 13.4.1 After making some minor updates to some files and building